# Implicit mapping based on column values

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to do an implicit mapping in EF6 that is based on the values of the various columns. I have a simple table like so...

```
col1  | col2   | col3
```

with each of the columns nullable. A dependency would be from a column that has an entry, e.g.

```
"bla" | "blub" | "qwer"
```

to any entry that has one or more of the rows at null but the others the same like ...

```
"bla" | null   | "qwer"
null  | "bulb" | "qwer"
null  | "blub" | null
```

is that somehow expressible as a "Map" operation or do I have to write a custom select for that (and if so, how)?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyDbType>()
  .HasMany(e => e.Dependents)
  .WithMany(e => e.DependsOn)
  .Map(m => m.???)
```

Comment: I believe it's not possible. The foreign keys must be defined for the entire table. You can't define foreign keys based on rows values.]

Comment: @FabioLuz ok, guess I'll do the resolution in code then ... not a big deal either, was just hoping for a builtin option.